# Custom Pagination in Laravel Yajra DataTable

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-blade, yajra-datatable

I love how the DataTables give us all the necessary things that we require in our Table but is there any way we can edit the pagination coming default with Laravel Yajra DataTable to our own. Really looking forward for someone who can guide me on this.

Comment: Can you explain in detail? which type of modification do you want?

Comment: By default Yajra DataTable comes with a very simple type of pagination which is having some very specfic page numbers I want to modfiy it with my own design where only we can see first page and last page and with them there should be the buttons of next and previous to goto next page and previous page.